# Java scanner to ignore delimiter in csv in case of ""

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am using scanner to delimiting tokens by `";"`. I need when strings are quoted,
that ; would be ignored by scanner in quotes "". Also need delimiting by "".

```
             0          1                        2
A   ProjectID Name  Describtion                 Summary
B      ID-322;"oba stb; iba logo ""T"" ";dg-eiiod
C      ID-349;Sttring;dg-enc05
D      ID-888;Data;dg-enc05
```

As you see in string `"oba stb; iba logo`""T"" ";`is my delimiter.
I need to make scanner ignore it, now it would split it as`"oba stb"iba logo ""T"" "` which I don't want.

now I have
`scanner.useDelimiter(";|\t");`

Comment: inside quotes I want the scanner can read also "ID-322;""tryit" " ssss"

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Scanner` for parsing CSV files, **use a CSV parser**.

Almost all Java-based CSV parsers allow you to use delimiters other that commas.

E.g. with [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) (just to pick a random one):

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withDelimiter(';');
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset(); // or StandardCharsets.UTF_8
try (CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(file, charset, format)) {
    for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
        String projectID = record.get("ProjectID");
        String name = record.get("Name");
        String description = record.get("Describtion");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I recognize which format csv has, to use correct CSVFormat in if else? This solution manually specify the one type of format

Comment: @jirajira Your question is about a semicolon-separated file with quoted values. That is the file format, which you specify in code as shown here. What `if else` are you talking about?